# Creating a Temp table where the rows equal a number

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a temp table in sql server that will create a number of rows based on a number.

So I have a query that results the number 35 and I want to create a temp table with 35 rows with the ID values 1 - 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1
while (@i <= 35)
begin
  insert tmp (id) values (@i)
  set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I knew the answer was simple I just couldn't think of it.